# how to output text of elementById in DOM?

Tags: php, dom

It should be very simple. I am loading in php via DOMDocument();

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $el = $doc->getElementById('somethingId');
```

Lets say i have

> ```
> <html><head></head><body><div id="somethingId">my
> <span style="background:red">something else</span> 
> information</div></body></html>
> ```

Q1. How to echo whats inside that element ("my information") from $el?

Q2. How to echo whats inside and including span data (like innerHTML in javascript)?

Answer to Q2:

> $children = $el->childNodes;
>
> ```
> foreach ($children as $child) { 
>
>     $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
>
> }
> ```
>
> echo $innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  should do

```
echo ($el->nodeValue);
```

Comment: are brackets necessary? also i have added another question. Can you help. Thanks

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike: No, the brackets are not necessary. echo is not a function - it's a language construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_null($el)) {
        $content = $el->nodeValue;

        if (empty($content)) {
            $content = $el->textContent;
        }

        echo $content;
    }
```